# Exclude in git deleted important file

Tags: xcode, git

I have 2 branches master, testing. I `git checkout testing` and added an exclusion in .git/info/exclude

I added this into exclude: MyProject/MyProject.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj

I did this so it wouldnt prompt me to add it and commit it everytime because it changes whenever I change tab or stuff like that.

I committed this to testing and pushed, then I `git checkout master` and `git merge testing`.

In the terminal it said this: `delete mode 100644 MyProject/MyProject.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj`

And after this I cant open my xcode project anymore, it says `cannot be opened because it is missing its project.pbxproj file`

And now I cant seem to get it back, I cant find it in my github under commits. ;_;

Comment: Use the Terminal Git commands or the remote repository commands or a 3rd party app such as Tower to retrieve the project file. Or even TimeMachine.

Comment: I guess `git reflog` might help you get the commit before the one which messed up your project. then check out a branch from that commit.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you put this stuff in your `.gitignore` rather than `.git/info/exclude`.

To get it back you could check out the commit right before removing it (assuming there is such a commit), move it someplace safe, and then re-add it after switching back to master.

If it's a file that is needed in the repository, then making git ignore it doesn't really make any sense (think of the guy cloning a fresh copy). Perhaps you'll have to live with either committing changes to it all the time, or get into the habit of leaving that file unstaged most of the time.

Comment: A couple that might be worthwhile ignoring or excluding are: "User Interface State" and "Breakpoints_v2.xcbkptlist".